# Could a vulnerable disabled app be exploited?

Tags: android, security

Let's take for example "Android System WebView", that is known to be vulnerable in some of its versions. If a user disables a vulnerable app (with the integrated OS feature or some third-party apps call it "freeze"), is it still possible for an attacker to use its security flaw or it's just inaccessible in every way?

Comment: You may wish to explain, in detail, what "freezes a vulnerable app" means. I am not aware of any "integrated OS feature" in Android that uses the term '"freeze".

Comment: @CommonsWare : sorry I don't use an english OS so I wasn't aware how it's called in english. I updated the text. I'm speaking about the Disable button that you can see in each app page, in the settings screen.

Comment: It is not possible, unless the offender has root access.

Comment: @AaronGillion good, so that's a nice defense for non-rooted devices, but is there any official source or do we just suppose it?

Comment: I'm not satisfied. Some of my disabled apps still have the "Force Stop" button active, so at least one of their services is running, maybe started by a system app. So I think they still can be exploited, I'd like more opinions and sources.